# Can someone help understand the merge sort algorithm?

Tags: mergesort

My question is: in the `mergeSort` method we are diving the array into smaller and smaller arrays by using recursion, however I cannot fathom how where they are stored and how are we inputting all those arrays into the method sort when it is not recursive? For instance, let's say we have the numbers `2, 1, 5, 8, 9` into an array. Afterwards we will have 5 arrays, each with one element in them. So now we have to merge al of them, but how are the steps executed, what do we input to get two sorted arrays: `1, 2` and `5, 8, 9` which will merge to give `1, 2, 5, 8, 9`?

```java
public class main {

    // Helper method to print out the integer array.
    private static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Breaks down the array to single or null elements in array.
    private static int [] mergeSort(int[] array) {
        // Recursive control 'if' statement.
        if (array.length <= 1) {
            return array;
        }
        int midpoint = array.length / 2;
        // Declare and initialize left and right arrays.
        int[] left = new int[midpoint];
        int[] right;
        if (array.length % 2 == 0) { // if array.length is an even number.
            right = new int[midpoint];
        } else {
            right = new int[midpoint + 1];
        }

        // Populate the left and right arrays.
        for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < right.length; j++) {
            right[j] = array[midpoint+j];
        }

        int[] result = new int[array.length];

        // Recursive call for left and right arrays.
        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);

        // Get the merged left and right arrays.
        result = merge(left, right);

        // Return the sorted merged array.
        return result;
    }

    // Merges the left and right array in ascending order.

    private static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
        // Merged result array.

        int[] result = new int[left.length + right.length];

        // Declare and initialize pointers for all arrays.
        int leftPointer, rightPointer, resultPointer;
        leftPointer = rightPointer = resultPointer = 0;

        // While there are items in either array...

        while(leftPointer < left.length || rightPointer < right.length) {

            // If there are items in BOTH arrays...

            if (leftPointer < left.length && rightPointer < right.length) {

                // If left item is less than right item...

                if (left[leftPointer] < right[rightPointer]) {

                    result[resultPointer++] = left[leftPointer++];

                } else {

                    result[resultPointer++] = right[rightPointer++];
                }
            }

            // If there are only items in the left array...

            else if (leftPointer < left.length) {

                result[resultPointer++] = left[leftPointer++];
            }
            // If there are only items in the right array...

            else if (rightPointer < right.length) {
                result[resultPointer++] = right[rightPointer++];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Initial array with print out.

        int[] array = { 2, 1, 5, 8, 9 };

        System.out.println("Initial Array: ");

        printArray(array);

        // Sorted and merged array with print out.

        array = mergeSort(array);

        System.out.println("Sorted Array: ");

        printArray(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: is "not recursive" mandatory? it's quite cumbersome to implement not recursively IMO.. and you don't need to split the array itself but split the operation..

Answer (score 0):

The example code as written has a memory leak, it reassigns left and right with the result of mergeSort, losing what was allocated to left and right prior to the recursive calls to mergeSort.

The question mentions non-recursive sort, which would be a bottom up merge sort. Most library implementations for stable sorts are some variation of bottom up merge sort, such as a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort. Link to wiki article for basic logic of bottom up merge sort:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation

To explain bottom up merge sort, an array of n elements is considered as n runs of size 1, where a run of size 1 can be considered to be sorted. Then pairs of runs of size 1 are merged to create a sorted runs of size 2. Pairs of sorted runs of size 2 are merged to create sorted runs of size 4, and so on, until a merge produces a single sorted run. Top down is similar, except it recursively splits an array (normally by generating pairs of indexes for the start and end of runs), until it produces two runs of size 1, then and only then does the merge process begin, after which it follows the stack somewhat like a tree, depth first and left first.

Using the example array but reordered, 2 1 9 8 5, bottom up would look like this

```
|2 1 9 8 5|
|2|1|9|8|5|       split
|1 2|             merge
    |8 9|         merge
        |5|       copy
|1 2 8 9|         merge
        |5|       copy
|1 2 5 8 9|       merge
```

For top down:

```
|2 1 9 8 5|
|2 1 9|8 5|       split
|2 1|9|           split
|2|1|             split
|1 2|             merge
|1 2 9|           merge
      |8|5|       split
      |5 8|       merge
|1 2 5 8 9|       merge
```